# Configuring @me.com account on Adium

Tags: icloud, adium

I am trying to set up my iCloud (@me.com) account in Adium. But it never logs in, and it says that my password is wrong. However when I set it up in iChat it works fine.

I have googled for this sort of problem a bit, but found no answer.

Why is it happening?

Comment: We need more information. Does it keep asking you for your password when setting it up? Randomly?

Comment: It won't even log in. It says the password is wrong. It works on iChat though.

Answer (score 2):

Officially you cannot use third party clients for connecting to AIM with iCloud account. It seems that the protocol is the same, but authentication is different.

> AOL/Apple changed the authentication method for new iCloud accounts. This will have to be fixed in libpurple before it'll work again in Adium.

This quote is from this [board](http://www.cocoaforge.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=23808).

Try using a [nightly build](http://nightly.adium.im/) of Adium, if it's fixed — it's there.